# How can I run previously loaded Javascript using history.pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate

My site relies heavily on jQuery and other JavaScript libraries. There are a lot of UI effects that control how the page loads and access AJAX content, etc.

I also use a `history.pushState()` function to quicken load time.

```
$('.navLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.pushState(null, null, this.href);
    replacePage(this.href); // function to load content using .ajax()
});
```

I have sharpened other events using `.live()` to allow them to function after the `history.pushState()` has executed.

My issue is that I have other scripts that execute after the initial page load that do not render a second time after `history.pushState()`.

Some examples are simple Google Maps functions

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Which don't recognize the script call and/or library that was previously loaded.

So how can I have all my scripts humming perfectly while loading `history.pushState()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to trigger page initializer process manually because it depends on the page type. You could invoke initializer after AJAX content fetch successfully and has been append to DOM tree.

By the way, I think you need to register onpopstate event handler which respond for changing content when user trigger history back. And you have to record the stacked page necessary information (e.g., id, url) when you execute pushState() for AJAX content retrieving.

```
<a id="page1" class="nav" href="main">Page1</a>
<a id="page2" class="nav" href="map">Page2</a>
<a id="page3" class="navs" href="help">Page3</a>
<div id="content-wrapper">
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    //get ajax content and init it when user trigger history back
    window.onpopstate = function(event){
        getPage(event.state.id);
    }

    $(function(){
        $(".nav").click(function(){
            var pageInfo = {"id":this.id,"url":this.href};
            history.pushState(pageInfo, null, this.href);
            getPage(this.id);
        });
    });

    function getPage(pageId){
        $.get("http://mydomain/getPage/"+pageId,function(response){
            //append ajax content to container
            $("#content-wrapper").append(response.content);

            //invoke initializer according to page type
            initializer(pageId);
        });
    }

    function initializer(pageId){
        switch(pageId)
        {
            case "page1":
                break;
            case "page2":
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){
                    ........
                });
                break;
            case "page3":
                break; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this is helpful for you.